# About the version of each component in release 7.5 of FIWARE

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus, fiware-sth-comet

Currently I am going to verify FIWARE.
Release 7.5 was announced, but there are components whose version is lower in the core component.

- cygnus

  - Release7.4 : version2.0.0
  - Release7.5 : version1.9.0
- sth-comet

  - Release7.4 : version2.4.0
  - Release7.5 : version2.3.0

I want to know the reason why the version of the component is going down.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to Cygnus, the short history is that FIWARE wrongly used "Cygnus" as software name in FIWARE 7.4 for a component that in FIWARE 7.5 was renamed to ["Draco"](https://github.com/ging/fiware-draco). Cygnus stills existing of course but release 2.0.0 has not come yet. Last Cygnus available version in the moment of writting this is [Cygnus 1.10.0](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/releases/tag/1.10.0), to be included as part of FIWARE release 7.5.1.

With regards to STH, probably FIWARE releases are still using [this fork](https://github.com/ging/fiware-sth-comet) as reference, when it should be using [the original one](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-sth-comet). Note the original repository is the most updated and the one which uses version 2.4.0 at the present moment.

Answer (score 1):

@fgalan is correct, some elements were inconsistently labelled in release **7.4** and **7.5**. A patch [release](https://github.com/Fiware/catalogue/releases/tag/FIWARE_7.5.1) has finally corrected this.

As of **7.5.1**, the following versions are correct:

- cygnus **1.10.0**
- sth-comet **2.5.0**
- draco    **FIWARE_7.5**

The new draco generic enabler had been initially released as cygnus 2.x which was incorrect.